# What does "Synchronize" paramter of Install-SPSolution do?

Tags: powershell, deployment, solution-package

[Install-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534%28v=office.15%29.aspx) command can accept an optional `Synchronize` parameter. MSDN says that it "synchronizes all solutions or the specified solution in the local farm". But what does this mean? What exactly does the parameter do? When should it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of detail.

Performs a synchronization of the Windows SharePoint Services Solution Package (WSP) solutions stored in the configuration database with the files stored on disk. The .wsp files will be synchronized in the order in which they were submitted to the server.

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262688%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

This is same as Syncsolution in SP 2007.

So bottom line, Synchronization is done within two things

Changes in File System **WITH** Changes in Content DB

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves you problem !